# Document Layout Styles

Tags: sectioning, packages, typography, grid-typesetting

I am inviting partial solutions for defining styles for document layouts. The solutions should be capable of defining the font size, leading (interline distance), and type for the running text *as well* as the style for sectional unit titles. Please see below for a definition of partial solution.

Particular care should be taken that the styles for the sectional unit titles integrate nicely with the style of the running text, so the running text should flow neatly around the titles, *making sure the distance between any two lines of running text on any page is always a multiple of the user-defined leading.*

There are some partial solutions to this question. For example, the `grid` package is a good starting point.

I don't have a particular application for any solution (answer) to my question: I posted the question, hoping that others may find the answers interesting. This is why I do not provide an MWE.

To make up for the lack of an MWE, I promise I'll award a 500-reputation bounty in one week for the best current solution, provided it shows some promise. I'll award another 500-reputation bounty in two weeks. (In the unlikely event that I'll have 500 reputation left after two weeks, I'll ward one more 500-reputation bounty in three weeks:-).

**Edit 3 September, 2015. The total 1000 reputation has been awarded. I can't respond to any further comments about this question. Also I won't be able to comment on any further solutions.

**Partial Solution** A partial solution may assume documents don't have displayed mathematical equations and other user-defined displays because displays may upset the inter-line distance. Furthermore, a partial solution may assume that all floats (figures, tables, etc.) are positioned at the top or bottom of the page.

Comment: I'm expectating about this subject. It will be useful to me, but I don't hace the knowledge to propose solution. It's a too good idea!

Comment: Hopefully, grid typesetting will progress thanks to your question. LaTeX only, or is XeLaTeX acceptable as well (say, using free fonts)? If time allows I will try to write a solution.

Comment: by `user-defined displays` you mean `equations, minipages, tabular...`?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen No such thing as a simple solution!

Comment: Would this be a possible candidate for what you're looking for? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35093/3954

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I could add a preliminary version allowing this (of course, not as elaborate as the one provided by `titlesec`, for example).

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Two questions (though I have no time to answer for the foreseeable future). – Should it work with consecutive headings (i.e. no text between them)? And how about footnotes? I see no *harmonious* solution except to stick them at the bottom with their own leading and alignment. Same with headings that span over several lines… the only harmonious solution is to break the grid (though with sufficient leading, one can have everything up to the section ≤ \baselineskip).

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I can't see why you consider my solution is not working :-(  well :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Is what a bug?

Comment: @cfr The comment i answered to is deleted now, my own deleted as well. :-)

Comment: @ienissei Ideally it should work with LaTeX. You may assume there are no footnotes, but if you do implement them, they should not interfere with the inter-line spacing of the running text. You may also assume there are no consecutive headings.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Looks nice but from the examples it's not clear whether it's easy to change the style for sectional units.

Answer (score 18):

Here a partial solution

**Update: New solution** this is (a new package `baseline.sty`)

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}%
\ProvidesPackage{baseline}%

\edef\mtf@size{\f@size} 
\edef\mtf@baselineskip{\f@baselineskip} 
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\mtf@size\mtf@baselineskip
   \abovedisplayskip \mtf@baselineskip
   \abovedisplayshortskip \abovedisplayskip 
   \belowdisplayshortskip \abovedisplayskip 
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize%
%%%
\newcounter{nbs}
\newlength\mttempa
\let\mtset@fontsize\set@fontsize
\def\set@fontsize#1#2#3{%
\ifdim #2 pt<\mtf@baselineskip
\mtset@fontsize{#1}{#2}{\mtf@baselineskip}%
\else
\PackageWarning{baseline}{may be the font is used with modified baseline}%
\setcounter{nbs}{0}%
\setlength{\mttempa}{#2 pt}%
\loop
\stepcounter{nbs}%
\addtolength\mttempa{-\mtf@baselineskip}%
\ifdim\mttempa>0pt 
\repeat%
\setlength{\mttempa}{\mtf@baselineskip}%
\loop
\addtocounter{nbs}{-1}%
\ifnum\value{nbs}>0
\addtolength\mttempa{\mtf@baselineskip}%
\repeat%
\mtset@fontsize{#1}{#2}{\mttempa}%
\fi}
%%%
\setlength\smallskipamount{\z@}
\setlength\medskipamount{\mtf@baselineskip}
\setlength\bigskipamount{\mtf@baselineskip}
\setlength\footnotesep{\z@}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{\mtf@baselineskip}
\setlength\floatsep    {\mtf@baselineskip}
\setlength\textfloatsep{\mtf@baselineskip}
\setlength\intextsep   {\mtf@baselineskip}
\setlength\dblfloatsep    {\mtf@baselineskip}
\setlength\dbltextfloatsep{\mtf@baselineskip}
\setlength\@fptop{\z@}
\setlength\@fpsep{\mtf@baselineskip}
\setlength\@fpbot{\z@}
\setlength\@dblfptop{\z@}
\setlength\@dblfpsep{\mtf@baselineskip}
\setlength\@dblfpbot{\z@}
\setlength\partopsep{\z@}
\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
            \parsep \z@  \topsep \z@ \itemsep\z@}
\let\@listI\@listi
\@listi
\def\@listii {\leftmargin\leftmarginii
              \labelwidth\leftmarginii
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
              \parsep \z@  \topsep \z@ \itemsep\z@}
\def\@listiii{\leftmargin\leftmarginiii
              \labelwidth\leftmarginiii
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
              \parsep \z@  \topsep \z@ \itemsep\z@}
\def\@listiv {\leftmargin\leftmarginiv
              \labelwidth\leftmarginiv
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listv  {\leftmargin\leftmarginv
              \labelwidth\leftmarginv
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listvi {\leftmargin\leftmarginvi
              \labelwidth\leftmarginvi
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\setlength\lineskip{\z@}
\setlength\normallineskip{\z@}
\setlength\lineskiplimit{-\maxdimen}
\setlength\parskip{\z@}
\jot=\mtf@baselineskip
\newcommand{\partlabelfnt}{\Large\bfseries}
\newcommand{\partfnt}{\huge\bfseries}
\newcommand{\secfnt}{\Large\bfseries}
\newcommand{\subsecfnt}{\large\bfseries}
\newcommand{\subsubsecfnt}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\newcommand{\paragraphfnt}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\newcommand{\subparagraphfnt}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\part{%
   \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
   \par
   \addvspace{2\mtf@baselineskip}%
   \@afterindentfalse
   \secdef\@part\@spart}

\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
       \partlabelfnt \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par\nobreak
     \fi
     \partfnt #2%
     \markboth{}{}\par}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip \mtf@baselineskip
    \@afterheading}
\def\@spart#1{%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \partfnt #1\par}%
     \nobreak
     \vskip \mtf@baselineskip
     \@afterheading}
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-\mtf@baselineskip}%
                                   {\mtf@baselineskip}%
                                   {\normalfont\secfnt}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-\mtf@baselineskip}%
                                     {1sp}%
                                     {\normalfont\subsecfnt}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-\mtf@baselineskip}%
                                     {-1em}%
                                     {\normalfont\subsubsecfnt}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {-\mtf@baselineskip}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\paragraphfnt}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}%
                                       {-\mtf@baselineskip}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\subparagraphfnt}}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{\mtf@baselineskip}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{\mtf@baselineskip}
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      {\leavevmode
       \large \bfseries #1\hfil \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
       \nobreak
       \if@compatibility
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
      \fi
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\renewcommand\indexspace{\par \vskip\mtf@baselineskip\relax}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \hrule\@width.4\columnwidth
  \kern3.5\p@}

\endinput
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{baseline}
%----------------------------------
%              just for the example
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{blindtext}
%----------------------------------
%                 just for the show
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw[blue!20!white,thin]
       (current page.south west) grid [ystep=12pt,xstep=\paperwidth] (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}
%----------------------------------
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blindmathtrue
\blindtext
\begin{center}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
\end{center}
\begin{theorem}
\blindtext
 \[\bar x = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x_i = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \dots{} + x_n}{n}\]
\end{theorem}
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

**User guide guide** user interface:

**1)** The package uses default font size from class `10pt, 11pt, 12pt` or  `9pt, 14pt, 17pt` if allowed, for example if extarticle is used but the user can also
do

```
\documentclass{article}
\fontsize{15pt}{18pt}\selectfont
\usepackage{baseline}
```

**2)** The package use default setting from class article for section like heading (shape, size ...) but not vertical spacing of course. If the use want to change this setting, the pacckage provides commands for this

```
\renewcommand{\partlabelfnt}{......}   % default {\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\partfnt}{......}   % default {\huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\secfnt}{......}   % default {\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\subsecfnt}{......}   % default {\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\subsubsecfnt}{......}   % default {\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\paragraphfnt}{......}   % default {\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\subparagraphfnt}{......}   % default {\normalsize\bfseries}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This may be a good start and the output looks good, but this solution does not have a particularly easy API for beginners. It would be nice if you could separate isolate the API in a separate style file and provide a key-value interface that lets the user define the style for the sectional unit headings. Ideally, the API should be monkey proof. E.g. it should only allow multiples of "standard leadings" for the (temporary) leading.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I'll try. for example  the user need only to set `\renewcommand{\secfnt}{<styleofsection>}` styleofsection default is `\sffamily\bfseries`

Comment: I note that it's impossible to change the size of the type in the sectional unit headings. Changing the size of the type should be possible (and to any size). Perhaps I'm missing something. A well-defined interface would help to understand the implementation as well as the API.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I'll update my answer by adding a new solution. I'll back to my original idea.

Comment: (I overlooked something earlier on.) I don't think this is what I'm looking for. For example if I do, `\renewcommand\subsecfnt{\tikz\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\Large\bfseries}\section{Hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello}\subsection{World hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello}` this affects the leading for the sectional unit titles. I would have hoped it wouldn't change. Also it would be nicer if there was a key-value API.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen sorry, I am not sure I understand you correctly but the fontsize `\Large` by default is 14.4pt so bigger than the unite baseline =12pt that's why it change. Try `\renewcommand\subsecfnt{\tikz\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\large\bfseries}`. Please informe me.

Comment: _Any_ size should be allowed. There are plenty of books that have sectional unit titles that don't fit the normal inter line spacing. For example, see [_LaTeX and Friends_](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-23816-1#page-1).

Comment: I think this is not so difficult, but I don't recommand it. I will see.

Comment: note `\setlength\lineskiplimit{-\maxdimen}` means that if the math takes up more space than three lines then it will over-print the following text.

Comment: I know it's not difficult. I implemented it myself:) All I'm looking for is something that's useful for the TeX community.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you, this is exactly what I was waiting for. I mean I know that this will cause problem, but what? thank you again, any advice?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen see http://justpaste.it/nf80

Comment: @touhami I _think_ for display things you have to intercept and add the right spacing "by hand" either by trapping the display in a box and measuring (the classic way) or by using \pdfsavepos (or wrappers such as tikzmark) to measure the vertical position after the display and adjust on the next run, or something else....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle (+1) I think you're right. That's about how I did it when I implemented this myself (but my solution isn't useful for the general public).

Comment: @touhami Please notice that there's no need to prove your solution works with (math) displays. It's stated explicitly in my question.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I figured it probably isn't what you mean. But I think you are making it sound rather simpler than it is. It is not just section headings, after all: at least you have to worry about the title etc., floats at the top of pages, lists, footnotes etc. And the results have to look *nice*.  Moreover, a user might, of course, switch font or fontsize without that being part of a custom display (i.e. not using a `center` environment or a `minipage` or `\parbox` which I assume are ruled out). Moreover, *inline* maths can also affect the spacing between lines, can it not?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I didn't really mean it that way. It was a point about how you were saying it. I didn't think that you meant it to come across as you did. And I didn't mean my comment to come across as it obviously did either. So I'm sorry that you understood it that way. I'll delete it but it was intended to be a point about communication rather than content. But, sadly, my communication is clearly no good either.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen And I would be sorry if you stopped contributing. Please do not (stop, that is).

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I thought the question was fine. I just thought you were being a bit hard on touhami.

Comment: @cfr For me it's not about difficulty it's about (sense?) I still don't understand what the OP mean about font size changing.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen please see my comment to cfr

Comment: @touhami I am not sure how to explain this better than I did in my question.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I excuse you. maybe it's me, I have the problem of explaining. But make sure you can use any size you want, if the font size is big of course the baseline will change (double or 3x, ...) in your comment you made subsection in Large so you make it as section style, if you think the baseline was changed because of `\tikz` no, you can try without it. did you see https://justpaste.it/nf80

Comment: I thought the idea was that the code would adjust in that case to ensure that the body text still started on a standard baseline. For example, if the definition of `\subsection` boxed the title, measured the height and then added some space to make it up to a multiple of `\baselineskip` or whatever. The title text would not necessarily be on the baseline but the requirement, as I understand it, is only for the running text to be. However, that approach would obviously fail for run-in titles. (But changing their size is dodgy anyway, I think.)

Comment: @cfr (+1) That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen and that is exactly what i do (I propose) in (last) page https://justpaste.it/nf80

Comment: @cfr please see my last comment

Comment: @touhami That would be with further modifications, right? (That is, the last case shown in the paste.) If so, yes, that's how I understood it although, as I say, I'm not sure how run-in titles are supposed to be handled. But it would seem to me reasonable for those to impose `\normalsize` since the running text cannot flow around them *nicely* otherwise ;).

Comment: @cfr you're right.

Comment: @touhami It doesn't work as expected: after `\renewcommand\secfnt{\Large\bfseries}` the leading of the section title is twice that of what you'd get if you used `\Large\bfseries` in the running text. Also (IMHO) a key-value interface would be easier for the user.

Comment: please try this `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{baseline}\begin{document}
\Large\bfseries
  the leading of the section title is twice that of what you'd get if you used 
  the leading of the section title is twice that of what you'd get if you used 
  the leading of the section title is twice that of what you'd get if you used 
\end{document}`   Manipulation of baselineskip is not so easy, for example, if you type `bla bla {\huge bla} bla` in standard latex document (without baseline.sty) the baselieskip will not change you need to start (or to end) a paragraph.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28767/discussion-on-answer-by-touhami-document-layout-styles).